# Displaying content in Angular without $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, mean-stack, angularjs-routing

I am trying to display content using Angular, angular UI-Router, and **without relying on $scope**.

In my `mainController`, I don't have any issues using directive likes `ng-repeat`. But I don't know how to access information from my `postsController`.

I know that I am pulling the correct data in my controller since console.log shows the correct post object. Now I just need to know how to access it.

index.html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html" >

    {{ }} // What do I put here?

</script>
```

app.js

```
app.config([
  '$stateProvider',
  '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      ...
      .state('posts', {
        url: '/posts/{id}',
        templateUrl: '/posts.html',
        controller: 'postsController'
      });
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
  }
]);
```

app.js

```
app.controller('postsController', [
  '$stateParams',
  'posts',
  function($stateParams, posts) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
    console.log(vm.post);
  }

]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You state will be using `controllerAs` so you need to define controller as below. And by using alias of your controller you could show data on view.

```
.state('posts', {
    url: '/posts/{id}',
    templateUrl: '/posts.html',
    controller: 'postsController as postCtrl'
});
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html" >
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="p in postCtrl.post">{{p}}</li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

You should have latest version like `0.2.0`+ version of `ui-router` to declare `controllerAs` like I suggested, for older version you could use @RadimKöhler suggestion.

Comment: Is this way more preferred? Or does it not really matter?

Comment: @JonRoby its totally depends on you which to follow..the way I suggested is added in the newer version to make the controller declaration one liner while using `controllerAs`

Answer (score 1):

You should use declaration **`controllerAs`**:

```
.state('posts', {
    url: '/posts/{id}',
    templateUrl: '/posts.html',
    controller: 'postsController',
    controllerAs: 'vm' // this will be injected into $scope
  });
```

and the view consume it like this:

```
{{vm.data | json }}
```

Comment: Is this convention more common than the answer below? Are there any advantages or disadvantages?